# How to bypass a website not accessible by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently building an API, in which I get links to website, and I make screenshots of these websites and store it in a csv file. However, some websites are not accessible due to regional policies, so my application crashes when it encounters such websites. Is there a way I can bypass those websites, and continue taking screenshots of other websites? Will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Bypassing access restrictions of a website is not a great topic for SO.

Comment: It sounds like you need the python version of ty-catch, exception handling, etc. or even some simple error checking.  Another approach would be to have a controller process and worker sub-processes.  Some sub-processes will die but the controller will live on.  Also, a SQLite database might work better than CSV

Comment: _so my application crashes_ Can you show us an example of such a crash?  Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: I think some people are reading "bypass" as "bypass security" but I read it as "skip over" or "not scrape" -- you might want to edit the question to make clear which kind of "bypass" you want.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a residential proxy service like [smart proxy](https://smartproxy.com/) and use that.

It will fool websites to believe you are in another region. Its the defacto method for web scrapers.

Happy scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just apply a VPN to whatever machine you're running Selenium on. Regardless make sure what you're doing is ethical, you can also check if a certain element exists on the page that would be the result of a regional policy blocking it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).